# Delete a Image from php folder

Tags: php

```
<?php
include ('config.php');

echo '<script>confirm("Are you sure?");</script>';

if(isset($_GET['fileid']))
{
    $fileid = $_GET['fileid'];
    $target_dir = "img/";
    $target_file =  $target_dir .$_GET['fileid'];
    $query = "DELETE FROM file_info WHERE fileid='$fileid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $path = "img/".$row['filename'];

    if($result)
    {
         unlink($path);
         echo'<script>window.location ="table.php";</script>';
     }
    else
    {
         echo'<script>window.location ="table.php";</script>';
    }
 }
 ?>
```

I don't know why its not working.

This code is updating the database but not deleting file from folder need to delete it.

Comment: Delete query doesn't fetch data from database!!Instead you need to use select query!!

Comment: during deletion you won't get record. you need to fetch first and then delete the record. So first use `SELECT` statement and then go for `DELETE` statement.

Comment: You should also be careful passing $_GET parameters directly to a SQL query. One could easily pass `1 OR 1=1` as `fileid` which will delete all records from your `file_info` table. Use prepared statements or typecast `fileid` to int if the `fileid` field is an integer in your DB

Answer (score 0):

with select query get filename using fileid. then execute delete statement.

```
<?php
 $path = "img/".$row['filename'];
if( file_exists ( $path ))
    unlink( $path);
else
 echo "file not found";

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

print the $result & cross check that whether you are able to reach inside if() block. Also from where you get the value `$row['filename']` To get it select the value first using select query.

Answer (score 0):

Change delete query to select and Give the absolute Path and fetch associative array for `$row['filename']`

**CODE**

```
$fileid = $_GET['fileid'];
$target_dir = "img/";
$target_file =  $target_dir .$_GET['fileid'];
$query = "SELECT filename FROM file_info WHERE fileid='$fileid'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); // And fetch assoc array

$path = "c:\project\img\".$row['filename'];
```